# Are there any injection vulnerabilities in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, code-injection

It's not about `eval()`

Let say I have #password input, and I send this data as a part of JSON object

```
var toSend = {
    text: 'hello',
    pass: $("#password").val()
};
```

Do I need to validate input?
Would `", you: "are hacked"` be interpreted on another side of communication as single string or empty string and another property?

**edit**: Nothing would happen in browser environment, but if JSON would be sent over internet as plain text and parsed again?

Comment: All user submitted data is evil and must be cleansed.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson: Not in this case. Parser does it automatically

Comment: never trust user input, no matter how secure the defaults are. that's one rule when dealing with these things. always be cautious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you would do the thing you're describing, nothing would happen, as json is being escaped (if you're using parser (JS object -> JSON))

> Nothing would happen in browser environment, but if JSON would be sent over internet as plain text and parsed again?

If you're parsing string version (JSON) to JS object, all values are unesecaped, so you have to escape them afterwards.

Comment: To be precise, stringify escapes it, and parse unescapes it.

Comment: @Neil: very well said. Edited my question, thanks. Hmm, how would you call a tool to stringify a JS object?

Comment: @Martin: JS-O-String-O-Mate? :D